# How to total an Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to sum a column with it rounding up and or down in the same cell. Can this be done?

Comment: Please provide us with some example data and result you expect.

Answer (score 3):

`=ROUND(SUM(FirstCell:LastCell), precision)` would be the formula you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add values rounded before addition (I think your question is ambiguous on this point) then to `0` decimal points for range A1:A5 try:

> =SUM(ROUND(A1:A5,0))

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.